# What is difference between if($a) and if($a==1)?

Tags: php

```
    function foo($a)
    { 
      if($a) {return "a";}
      else if($a==2) {return "b";}
      else {return "c";}
     }

     -----------------------------------------

     function foo2($a)
     {
       if($a==1){return "a";}
       if($a==2){return "b";}
       if($a==3){return "c";}

     }
```

when i passed value any number frim 1,2 or 3 ? it will return 1. when i pass value in function foo2 it will return value as value passed .

But why is difference coming ?

Answer (score 4):

When you do something like `if ($a)`, consider that PHP is a [weak typed language](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php). To understand what is evaluated in `if ($a)`, see the [conversion rules for booleans](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting).

Quoting from the manual:

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered `FALSE`:
>
> - the boolean `FALSE` itself
> - the integer `0` (zero)
> - the float `0.0` (zero)
> - the empty string, and the string `"0"`
> - an array with zero elements
> - an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
> - the special type `NULL` (including unset variables)
> - `SimpleXML` objects created from empty tags

All the others are considered `TRUE`, including `-1` (remarkable!).

On the other hand, when you do `if ($somevar == 1)`, then `$somevar == 1` is already a `boolean`, and conversion rules don't apply.

Comment: Much better written than my attempt. Nicely put.

Comment: Sends shivers down my spine. Especially the last one.

Comment: I am very thank full for your briefly anwers @PhilipWhitehouse ,@louism

Answer (score 1):

`if($a)` **any** non-zero value is `true`.

`if($a==1)` **only** 1 value is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

If `$a` is `true`, it will *not* return `1`, and *that* is the difference.

Answer (score -1):

`if($a)` means the same as: "if a is true, do this"

In PHP (and most other languages), the value of 0 means false and any other value is 'true'